Information rate of ultra-information-sparse languages
Pellegrino 2011
Also Pellegrino
YoonMi
These popular researches found out information density (ID) inversely correlates with speech rate (SR) to make information rate (IR) of languages cluster around 39 bit/sec.
The study of Yoonmi Oh find out the IR of information sparse language is a bit lower than information dense language (by comparing reading texts aloud).
My answer of word length of some extra-long numerals
In many texts translated, ultra-information-sparse languages (eg. Greenlandic Hawaiian) are much longer. I believe those ultra-information-sparse languages have a significantly lower IR (when reading a text alone) as speech rate has a physical limit. As suggested in the study above, any research of IR of ultra-information-sparse language? (could be measured in #segments)
#Segments Swadesh list
This is the only study I found which measures #segments.
My questions of word length differences between basic VS advanced vocabulary
